# php, java code direct integration

Tags: java, php

I need a way to directly integrate a php code with a java one. I know there is a software bridge to achieve that, but I need to know whether there exist a more direct link, via commands only. I meant to integrate java code into php code.

Comment: You mean to integrate php into java, or java into php?

Comment: java code into php code

Comment: Java is compiled. PHP is an interpreted script. How could that be possibly achieved?

Comment: Use http, or sockets.

Comment: You need to describe more accurately what you mean with integration. If PHP is a service (or component), I would recommend using REST or SOAP over http..